# golang get only one stat from json

Tags: go

i tried to get one stat from web api request in json.
This is what called https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ethereum/

I use this github code example `// Get info about coin`

```
coinInfo, err := coinApi.GetCoinData("ethereum")
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
} else {
    fmt.Println(coinInfo)
}
```

My result in log says

```
{ethereum Ethereum ETH 2 830.48 0.100287 3.23573e+09 8.0977392218e+10 9.7506734e+07 9.7506734e+07 0.61 -0.65 -7.36 1518176353}
```

But i want only the price_usd if you look at the api domain. Why cannot get only price?
Already tried `coinInfo['price_usd']` but its all not working

Here you find the functions to run the GetCoinData 
https://github.com/miguelmota/go-coinmarketcap/blob/master/coinmarketcap.go

Can someone help me to get only the price_usd from api in golang?

Comment: Have you tried anything? The simplest solution is to [Unmarshal](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) it. If you want only what field, you could unmarshal into a struct that contains only that field name.

Comment: @Marc: The simplest solution is to RTFM. No Unmarshaling is necessary (or even supported at that level).

Comment: That's definitely better. I saw json in the title and didn't examine the logs carefully. So yes, it's just a struct.

Comment: You have a link to RTFM? never heard this before. Working golang 2 days

Comment: @Scholli RTFM stands for "Read the f...ing manual" and is a more or less polite hint that you should probably get a clue about the very basics first ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://godoc.org/github.com/miguelmota/go-coinmarketcap#Coin), you can use the `PriceUsd` field of the `Coin` type for this.

Comment: like that? `fmt.Println(Coin["price_usd"])` than i get an error `storage/redis.go:890: undefined: Coin`

Comment: no, like `coinInfo.PriceUsd`. `Coin` is a struct, you just access its fields. Please take the [Go tour](https://tour.golang.org/), you seem really unfamiliar with the language.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot! That works! I am new 2 days on golang. I have a little done of the tour :)

Comment: Please take the entire tour, if you don't understand how structs and fields work in Go, you're not going to get very far with the language.